# Ubuntu 18.04 broken installaton - Netplan

Tags: networking, netplan

I have recently installed a fresh 18.04-lts ubuntu on a laptop. However, it is not possible to do much with it.

The first task involves connecting the machine to wifi which has been failing spectacularly.

My netplan config is as follows:

```
network:
   version: 2
   renderer: networkd
   wifis:
     wlp6s0:
       dhcp4: no
       dhcp6: no
       addresses: [192.168.1.63/24]
       gateway4: 192.168.1.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
     access-points:
       "xyz":
          password: "passpass"
```

The netplan *generate* and *apply* command pass without any errors but do not perform the desired setup.

Ubuntu has also been kind enough to not include basics utilities like wireless-tools in its iso files.

Is there any clear end-to-end guide available on how to get this working? I have noted that there open bugs and questions for this unresolved for the past two years.

Kindly avoid posting replies that involve downloading packages. These are meaningless to a machine prior to internet setup.

Comment: Is this a desktop or server installation? When using static IPs, you probably have to reboot.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using netplan directly for configuring networking on a desktop, rather than using NetworkManager, which is the default?